# Connection With Azure to MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, azure, apache-spark, pyspark, azure-databricks

I am trying to connect Azure Databricks with MongoDB, but I am getting an error message which I am not able to resolve.

I am getting the following error

```
com.mongodb.MongoTimeoutException: Timed out after 30000 ms while waiting to connect. Client view of cluster state is {type=UNKNOWN, servers=[{address=sopt-bo-halo-01.northeurope.cloudapp.azure.com:27017, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING, exception={com.mongodb.MongoSocketWriteException: Exception sending message}, caused by {javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target}, caused by {sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target}, caused by {sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target}}, {address=sopt-bo-halo-03.northeurope.cloudapp.azure.com:27017, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING, exception={com.mongodb.MongoSocketWriteException: Exception sending message}, caused by {javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target}, caused by {sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target}, caused by {sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target}}, {address=sopt-bo-halo-02.northeurope.cloudapp.azure.com:27017, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING, exception={com.mongodb.MongoSocketWriteException: Exception sending message}, caused by {javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target}, caused by {sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target}, caused by {sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target}}]
```

```py
    from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
    database = "prod-backoffice"
    collection = "AmazonRegion"
    connectionString = ‘<Username>://<Password> @hostN 
    /defaultdb?
    ssl=true&readPreference=primary&maxIdleTimeMS=60000&connectTimeoutMS=10000&
    authSource=DBNAME &authMechanism=SCRAM-SHA-1&
    tlsAllowInvalidCertificates=true&tlsAllowInvalidHostnames=true
    &sslAllowConnectionsWithoutCertificates=true&sslInvalidHostNameAllowed=true'
    spark = SparkSession.builder\
    .appName("MongoSparkConnectorIntro")\
    .config('spark.mongodb.input.uri',connectionString)\
    .config('spark.mongodb.output.uri', connectionString)\
    .config('spark.jars.packages', 'org.mongodb.spark:mongo-spark-connector_2.12:3.0.1')\
    .getOrCreate()
    df = spark.read\
    .format("com.mongodb.spark.sql.DefaultSource")\
    .option("uri", connectionString)\
    .option("database", database)\
    .option("collection", collection)\
    .load()
```

Answer (score 0):

> **Connect MongoDB Atlas with DataBricks**

1. **Connection with databricks**

Connect and Enable Databricks clusters to the cluster by adding the external IP addresses for the Databricks cluster nodes to the whitelist in Atlas.

[image]

**Access on MongoDB  Network  and add the Databrick cluster IP address.**

2. **Configure Databricks Cluster with MongoDB Connection URI**

- Get the MongoDB connection URI. click the cluster you have created in the MongoDB Atlas UI.
- Click the Connect button.
- Click Connect Your Application.

[image]

3. According to your Databrick MongoDB connector configuration make sure your scala and spark version

[image]

4. Copy the generated connection string. It should look like **mongodb+srv://:@Firstdatabase-wlcof.azure.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true**
5. Replace password and Firstdatabase name with your password and database name.

**Configuration in DataBricks**

**METHOD 1**

In your databricks cluster, select the **configuration tab** and click the **edit button** -> under advanced options, Please select the **spark configuration tab** using the connection string and update the spark config. Follow the below format in the config tab

```
spark.mongodb.output.uri<connection-string>

spark.mongodb.input.uri<connection-string>
```

**METHOD 2**

In python notebook configure settings directly using below code.

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

database = "<datanase_name>" #your database name

collection = "millionsongs" #your collection name

connectionString= copy your connection string here  ('mongodb+srv://user:<password>@cluster0.9rvsi.mongodb.net/<database>?retryWrites=true&w=majority')

spark = SparkSession

.builder

.config('spark.mongodb.input.uri',connectionString)

.config('spark.mongodb.input.uri', connectionString)

.config('spark.jars.packages', 'org.mongodb.spark:mongo-spark-connector_2.12:3.0.1')

.getOrCreate()

#Reading from MongoDB

df = spark.read

.format("com.mongodb.spark.sql.DefaultSource")

.option("uri", connectionString)

.option("database", database)

.option("collection", collection)

.load()
```

Comment: I have done this steps. I am getting the following error unable to find valid certification path to requested target.

Comment: This is a bad approach 
Azure Databricks have a dynamic IP, so you will be changing IP's again and again.
Either create a NAT GW in azure and use that static 
OR look into private endpoints